# why ng-click function does not increment (Angular JS and Ionic)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a quiz with **Angular JS** and **Ionic Framework**. My problem is;

The "Continue" button does not work, which should bring (with ng-click) the next question.

```
            <div class="btn" ng-click="selectContinue()">Continue</div>
```

and the function is:

```
 $scope.selectContinue = function(){
            return $scope.activeQuestion += 1;
        }
```

[image]

```
<div class="feedback">
                <p ng-show="myQuestion.correctness === 'correct'">You are <strong>correct</strong>.</p>
                <p ng-show="myQuestion.correctness === 'incorrect'">Oops! That is not correct.</p>
                <p>{{ myQuestion.feedback }}</p>
                <div class="btn" ng-click="selectContinue()">Continue</div>
            </div>
```

Here you can see the **app.js**
selectContinue function is at the bottom:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('QuizController', ['$scope','$http','$sce',function($scope,$http,$sce){

        $scope.score = 0;
        $scope.activeQuestion = -1;
        $scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0;
        $scope.percentage = 0;

        /* Get stored data */ 
        $http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
            $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
            /* Number of questions used in results */
            $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;

        });

        $scope.selectAnswer = function(qIndex,aIndex) {

            // Wheater or not the question is answered
            var questionState = $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState;

            if( questionState != 'answered' ){
                $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].selectedAnswer = aIndex;
                // Check this selected answer based on what the user has clicked on
                var correctAnswer = $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correct;
                $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer = correctAnswer;

                if( aIndex === correctAnswer ){
                    $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctness = 'correct';
                    $scope.score += 1;
                }else {
                    $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctness = 'incorrect';
                }

                $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState = 'answered';

            }
        }

        $scope.isSelected = function(qIndex,aIndex) {
            return $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].selectedAnswer === aIndex;
        }

        $scope.isCorrect = function(qIndex,aIndex) {
            return $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctAnswer === aIndex;
        }

        $scope.selectContinue = function(){
            return $scope.activeQuestion += 1;
        }

    }]);
```

**index.html** is below if you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="QuizController">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>

          <h1>Test Your Knowledge</h1>
       <div class="progress">
        <div class=" {{ ($index === activeQuestion) ? 'on' : 'off' }} " ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Inline conditional JS statement:
        If the activeQuestion greater than 1 -->
    <div class="intro {{ (activeQuestion > -1) ? 'inactive' : 'active' }}">

        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <p>Click begin to test your knowledge of Saturn.</p>
        <!-- activeQuestion variable will be set to 0 -->
        <p class="btn" ng-click="activeQuestion = 0">Begin</p>

    </div>

                <!-- Array of questions -->
        <div class="question 
            <!-- inline conditional statement -->
            {{ $index === activeQuestion ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}
            {{ myQuestion.questionState === 'answered' ? 'answered' : 'unanswered' }}
            " ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
            <p class="txt">{{myQuestion.question}}</p>
            <!-- Array of possible answers -->
            <p class="ans" 
                ng-class="{ 
                    selected: isSelected($parent.$index, $index), 
                    correct: isCorrect($parent.$index, $index) 
                }"
                ng-click="selectAnswer($parent.$index, $index)"
                ng-repeat="Answer in myQuestions[$index].answers">
                {{Answer.text}}
            </p>

            <div class="feedback">
                <p ng-show="myQuestion.correctness === 'correct'">You are <strong>correct</strong>.</p>
                <p ng-show="myQuestion.correctness === 'incorrect'">Oops! That is not correct.</p>
                <p>{{ myQuestion.feedback }}</p>
                <div class="btn" ng-click="selectContinue()">Continue</div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="results">
            <h3>Results</h3>
            <p>You scored x% by corretly answering x of the total x questions.  </p>
        </div>






      </ion-content>
        <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
            <a class="tab-item">
                <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
                    Home
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item">
                <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
                    Lesson
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item">
                <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i>
                    Quiz
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
/* Empty. Add your own CSS if you like */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:900|Roboto:400,100);

body { background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; }

/* Main Container 
=================== */
.scroll-content {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;
    /*  width: 650px; height: 650px; */
    position: relative; /* Others -absolute positinoed- will get position in relation to this position */
    overflow: hidden; /* anything outside of myQuiz container will be clipped or masked */
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.scroll-content h2 {font-size: 3em; margin: 0px; font-weight: 100; }
.scroll-content h3 {font-size: 2.4em; margin: 0px; font-weight: 100; }
.scroll-content p { margin: 0px 0px 14px 0px; }
.scroll-content .btn {
    display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; background-color: red;
    color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px; border-radius: 6px;
}

.scroll-content h1 {
    font-weight: 100; font-size: 2em; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px;
    position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 36px;
}

/* Progress Bar */
.scroll-content .progress {
    width: 550px; position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 40px;
}

.scroll-content .progress div {
    position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 30px; height: 30px; margin-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%; background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.2); transition: background-color 1s;
}

.scroll-content .progress div.on, 
.scroll-content .progress div.answered {
    background-color: #efbe5e;
}

/* Intro */
.scroll-content .intro { position: absolute; top: 225px; left: 2660px; width: 550px; }
.scroll-content .intro  p { margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px; }

/* Questions */
.scroll-content .question {
    width:550px; position: absolute; top: 225px; left: 2660px;
}

.scroll-content .question .txt {
    font-size: 1.6em; margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.scroll-content .question .ans {
    display: inline-block; font-size: 1.1em; width: 225px; border: 2px solid rgba(238,189,102,.4);
    border-radius: 6px; padding: 10px; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px; position: relative;
}


.scroll-content  .question .ans.selected {
    border-color: #be4b16; 
}


.scroll-content  .question .ans.correct {
    border-color: #459a2e; 
}

/* Insert corecct or incorrect images */
.scroll-content .question .ans::after {
    content:''; display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px;
    background: no-repeat: 0px 0px; background-size: 40px 40px;
    position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;
}

.scroll-content .question .ans.selected::after {
    background-image: url(../img/close-circled.png)
}
.scroll-content .question .ans.correct::after {
    background-image: url(../img/checkmark-circled.png)
}

.scroll-content .question .ans.selected::after {
    background-image: url(../img/close-circled.png)
}
.scroll-content .ans.correct::after {
    background-image: url(../img/checkmark-circled.png)
}

.scroll-content .question.unanswered .ans {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.scroll-content .question.unanswered .ans:hover {
    background-color: mediumvioletred;
}


.scroll-content .question.answered .ans {
    cursor: default;
}


/* Feedback */
.scroll-content .feedback {
    color: #efbe5e; margin-top: 10px; transition: opacity 1.5s, margin-top 1.5s;
    visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;
}

.scroll-content .feedback .btn {
    margin-top; 5px;
}

.scroll-content .feedback strong {
    color: #fff;
}

.scroll-content .answered .feedback {
    visibility: visible; opacity: 1; margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Results */
.scroll-content .results {
    position: absolute; top: 225px; left: 2660px; right: 40px;
}


.scroll-content .active, .scroll-content .inactive {
    transition: left 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.scroll-content .active {
    left: 40px;
}

.scroll-content .intro.inactive, .scroll-content .inactive.answered { left: -1350px;}










.start-quiz {
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid green;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.start-lesson {
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid green;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.pane {
    background-color: #3498db;
}
```

Why does ng-click not work?

Comment: just do `$scope.activeQuestion +=1 ; return $scope.activeQuestion`

Comment: Create a sample in play.ionic.com

Comment: @reptilicus in which part do yo mean?

Comment: @tommoc http://play.ionic.io/ seems offline.

Comment: Well, you're incrementing the `activeQuestion`.. and? Do you want it to move to the next question? This increment will not the change the question displayed with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems $scope.activeQuestion is not updated in angular context. That is why it does not reflect over UI. And also there is no need to return the updated value from selectContinue() method.

Try below code:

```
.controller('QuizController', ['$scope','$http','$sce', '$timeout',function($scope,$http,$sce, $timeout){

       ....
       $scope.selectContinue = function(){
            $timeout(function() {
               $scope.activeQuestion += 1;
            });
        }
});
```

It should work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not change anything.

Actually everything works without Ionic Framework. With only index.html and app.js, the next question comes with this ng-click and function in app.js. After integrating into Ionic, everything works until 2nd question.